# How come my accepted percentage is so low?

Tags: support

I found out about the feature today and accepted about 10 answers giving to about 25 questions of mine. It seems however my accepted percentage is still only 8%?

Comment: For values of 10 equal to 5 ;-)

Answer (score 5):

It'll probably be alright tomorrow. From [How does accepting an answer work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) on Meta Stack Overflow:

> - The accept rate is heavily cached and can take 24 hours or more to update.

There are also a number of things that do not count towards the accept rate calculation.

> **Which questions do not affect the accept rate?**
>
> - Community Wiki questions
> - Closed questions
> - Questions with no answers

Comment: It has not been updated still? It seems to take really long.